# Why does express/mongodb updateOne post allow $set of some values, but will not update others?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I am baffled by this post method, it will update fields 'x and y', but any attempt to set an array of widgets fails.
It is finding the correct item to update, passing all the required information through, but it will not allow insertion of, or update to 'widgets' fields.

Even if I remove the data intended for widgets and arbitrarily send through 'foo' it will not update with a field 'widgets'.

What am I doing wrong here???

**API Call to Update Widgets. The Arbitrary X and Y values will update on the database, but any attempt to update widget makes no change**

```
const saveUpdatedWidgets = async (update, _id) => {
    console.log("called to update widgets ",update.widgets," in pagecard saveUpdatedWidgets")
    let widgetObject = []
    for(let u=0;u<update.widgets.length;u++){
        widgetObject.push({
            id: update.widgets[u].id,
            text: update.widgets[u].text
        })
    }
    Api.withToken().post('/pagewidget/'+_id,
        {widgets: widgetObject, x:250, y:250}
    ).then(function (response) {
        console.log("?worked ",response.data)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("page save failed for some reason on pagecard: ",error.response);
    });
};
```

This will return the following in the console:

[image: Console for saveUpdatedWidgets method]

**Code for post method is:**

```
//THIS ROUTER WILL NOT UPDATE ANY WIDGETS FOR SOME REASON
router.post('/pagewidget/:_id',auth, async(req,res)=>{
    console.log("request to update ",req.body," for id ",req.params," in pagewidgetsave post")
    const query = { "_id": req.params };
    const addedWidgets = req.body;
    const newValues = { $set: addedWidgets }
    try {
        const thePage = await Pages.updateOne( query, newValues);
        res.status(201).send(thePage)
        console.log("updated Page: ",thePage);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

**Results from the console running node shows that values are going through, but only x and y actually update in database..**

[image: node console]

[image: console response to call]

**Here is the axios api.js file if there are any issues here:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3001"

export default {
  
  noToken() {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL
    });
  },
  
  withToken() {
    const tokenStr = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token")
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL,
      headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${tokenStr}`}
    });
  } 
}
```

What is going on!!?? It finds the page OK, and updates x and y values, but can't update widgets, even if the values for widget are just a string or number...

Comment: Try logging `query` and `newValues` right before you call `updateOne`

Comment: query is  { _id: { _id: '617626a7179ca4113034d82e' } }
newValues is  { '$set': { widgets: [ [Object] ], x: 250, y: 250 } }

Comment: Are the quotes which are put around $set the issue? The $set does seem to be working because it will update x and y whenever I change them in the database manually and then drag a widget to trigger the function..

Comment: WAIT, I think I see it, there is a double _id tag there. _id {_id

Comment: May have spoken too soon, after removing the double ID tag it is still updating x and y values, but will not add widgets (even if I pass '2' as the value instead of the widget objects)

Comment: query is  { _id: '617626a7179ca4113034d82e' }
newValues is  { '$set': { widgets: 2, x: 250, y: 250 } }  this will reset the pages x and y values as 250 each, but will not add a new field for widgets storing '2'

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. the MongoDB documentation doesn't mention this too well, and in its examples for updateOne() it passes an object for the update argument.
BUT, if you are setting a new field, this argument must be wrapped inside an array to use $set, this is because it can accept both methods to $set and to $unset. ([see mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/))
(i.e. updateOne({query} , [{$set: {field:"value"}, {$unset: {otherfield:"othervalue"}])

In the end the post method just had to change to const thePage = await Pages.updateOne( query, [newValues]); (with newValues stored as an object inside an array, to allow addition of $unset if it was needed.

This is why it would update existing values OK, but it would not set new values into the database.

What a journey....

**Full code for post method here**

```
router.post('/pagewidget/:_id',auth, async(req,res)=>{
    const query = {"_id": req.params._id};
    const addedWidgets = req.body;
    const newValues = { $set: addedWidgets }
    try {
        const thePage = await Pages.updateOne( query, [newValues]);
        res.status(201).send(thePage)
        console.log("updated Page: ",thePage);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: _"...this argument must be wrapped inside an array to use $set..."_. The update method takes, mainly, two arguments - the _filter_ and the _update_.The update can be a _regular_ update operation _or_ an Update with Aggregation Pipeline. These two ways of updates  have different purposes. What you are referring as "wrapped inside an array" is the Update with Aggregation Pipeline.